# Android timer Seconds counts down fast

Tags: android

```
    new CountDownTimer(400000, 100) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            Timer.setText((millisUntilFinished / 10000)+":"+(millisUntilFinished % 6000 / 100));

        }

        public void onFinish() {
            Timer.setText("done!");

            Intent intent = new Intent(ExamActivity.this,ResultActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("Score", score);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();       
        }
    }.start();
```

The issue is That the Seconds count Down So fast. i am trying to achieve a 40minutes count down..above is my code

Comment: You are counting in **centiseconds** intervals, not in **milliseconds**. See `new CountDownTimer(400000, 100)`

Comment: ok....how do i count in milliseconds?

Comment: its counting the seconds down by 10.. that is 59,49,39,29....

Comment: ok...please post the real code...thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you want 40 minutes try this:

```
new CountDownTimer(40*60*1000, 1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

visit [CountDownTimer Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html)

```
 new CountDownTimer(2400000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            Timer.setText((millisUntilFinished / 10000)+":"+(millisUntilFinished % 6000 / 100));

        }

        public void onFinish() {
            Timer.setText("done!");

            Intent intent = new Intent(ExamActivity.this,ResultActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("Score", score);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();       
        }
    }.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You were counting in centiseconds intervals, not in milliseconds.

Try setting it separately.

```
 new CountDownTimer(40*60*1000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            Timer.setText((millisUntilFinished / 10000)+":"+(millisUntilFinished % 6000 / 100));

        }

        public void onFinish() {
            Timer.setText("done!");

            Intent intent = new Intent(ExamActivity.this,ResultActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("Score", score);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();       
        }
    }.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new CountDownTimer(40*60*1000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

        long minute=    millisUntilFinished / (1000*60);
        long second=    (millisUntilFinished -(minute*60*1000))/1000;

            Timer.setText(minute+":"+
                    second);

        }

        public void onFinish() {
            Timer.setText("done!");

                            Intent intent = new Intent(ExamActivity.this,ResultActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra("Score", score);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();       
        }
    }.start();
}
```